# Running Node app through Grunt

Tags: node.js, process, gruntjs, spawn

I am trying to run my Node application as a Grunt task. I need to spawn this as a child process, however, to allow me to run the watch task in parallel.

This works:

```
grunt.registerTask('start', function () {
  grunt.util.spawn(
    { cmd: 'node'
    , args: ['app.js']
    })

  grunt.task.run('watch:app')
})
```

However, when changes are detected by the watch task, this will trigger the start task again. Before I spawn another child process of my Node app, I need to kill the previous one.

I can't figure out how to kill the process, however. Something like this does not work:

```
var child

grunt.registerTask('start', function () {
  if (child) child.kill()
  child = grunt.util.spawn(
    { cmd: 'node'
    , args: ['app.js']
    })

  grunt.task.run('watch:app')
})
```

It appears that:

1. Even though I store the spawned process in a variable outside of the function context, it does not persist, so the next time the start task is run, child is `undefined`.
2. `child` has no `kill` function…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `grunt-contrib-watch` currently spawns all task runs as child processes. So the variable `child` is not within the same process context. Fairly soon, `grunt-contrib-watch@0.3.0` will be released with a `nospawn` option. This will let you configure the watch to spawn task runs within the same context and would make your above example work.

Take a look at this issue for a little more information:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/45

Comment: I've just replaced my `grunt-contrib-watch` module with the [nospawn](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/tree/nospawn) branch and set the `nospawn` option to true: https://gist.github.com/OliverJAsh/5021187. `child` is still not defined on the second function call. Also, do you know how I can kill the child process?

Comment: The Gruntfile isnt a json file, only a js file. You also dont need to call the watch task with grunt.task.run(). Here is an example using the watch to share context: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/nospawn/test/fixtures/nospawn/Gruntfile.js#L35

Comment: To kill a child process do: `child.kill('SIGINT');`

Comment: It is JS, I just extracted the bit that was relevant, sorry for the confusion. I can't work out why `child` is undefined still, even though I'm sure `nospawn` is set to true and I have the right module installed.

Comment: Got it to work! The code demonstrated was correct, I just had something going on in my `package.json`. Thank you.

Comment: Although it works, I am getting this error: https://gist.github.com/OliverJAsh/5021819 (running Grunt with the `--stack` flag).

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work. That error causes Grunt to fail. It occurs when `watch` triggers the `start` task (second time).

Comment: Oh ha I was confused by your config. It appears that `grunt.util.spawn` requires the 2nd arg. So do `grunt.util.spawn({}, function() {});` The function is a callback called when the child process has finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Kyle. That fixed it! :) I can't believe my chances that the `nospawn` pull request happened just in time for this.

Comment: Cool. If you run into any issues feel free to open an issue on github. I'll publish the version with nospawn soon as v0.3.0. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I'm looking for a similar solution, would you mind posting your Gruntfile in a gist? Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example Gruntfile using nospawn: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/test/fixtures/nospawn/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [grunt-nodemon](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon) which handles a lot of the headaches related to spawning a child process.