# Why does grunt server stop immediately after being started?

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I have just started using keystoneJS and am trying to start my server with grunt.
The problem is that the server starts normally and immediately terminates.

Why is that?

here is console log:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xx>grunt express
Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
debugger listening on port 5858

------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS Started:
xxx is ready on port 3000
------------------------------------------------


Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2014-10-25 21:13:11 UTC)
loading tasks  64ms  ■■ 2%
express:dev      4s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 98%
Total 4.1s
```

Comment: If it's starting a background server, it starts the background task, then exits the script that starts the background task, but the background task is still running...

Comment: @torazaburo I'm trying to do this as fast as possible so I just need grunt to do as he's told, I do not wan't to rewrite everything by myself.

Comment: @Markasoftware That doesn't sound like something one might wan't to happen. How sure are you of this? My website isn't being run in the background once this is terminated.

Comment: Well, it says `Starting background Express server` in the output, so I'm just taking a guess at how it's working. And thats how forever works as well

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Use another port rather than 5858 as the debugger port

  ```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.listen(9998);
  ```
- Use another port rather than 3000 as the KeystoneJS port

  ```
  keystone.set('port', 9999)
  ```
- Use keepalive:

  ```
  nohup grunt connect::keepalive & #Linux

  Start-Process grunt connect::keepalive #Windows
  ```

**References**

- [KeystoneJS: Web Server Options](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#options-server)
- [grunt-contrib-connect: Connect Options](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/blob/master/docs/connect-options.md)
- [grunt-contrib-connect repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect)
- [nohup(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)
- [How to get grunt.js to start an express app for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857585/1113772)
- [grunt-contrib-connect works only with keepalive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593643/1113772)